# asp.NET ajax do a partial return during process

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

here is my problem :  I have an Update Panel with a asp:TextBox inside and an onTextChanged event. During the process, a loader.gif is show thanks to the progress Template.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="tboxEmailDegrade" runat="server" CssClass="cadreTexteRediger" MaxLength="250"
        AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="tboxEmailDegradeOnTextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Image ID="imgVerifEmailFalse" runat="server" ImageUrl="../../Charte/images/Avis/Formulaire/ko.gif"
        Visible="false" style="margin-left: 4px"/>
    <asp:Image ID="imgVerifEmailTrue" runat="server" ImageUrl="../../Charte/images/check.png"
        Visible="false" style="margin-left: 4px"/>
    <input id="HidStatutValide" type="hidden" value="0" runat="server" />
    <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server">
        <ProgressTemplate>
            <img class="iconeValdation" runat="server" src="../../Charte/images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Processing" style="margin-left: 4px; float:left" />
        </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>
</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="tboxEmailDegrade" />
</Triggers>
```

during that process i want to hide another image (in code imgVerifEmailTrue or imgVerifEmailFalse), but obviously the image will be hidden only at the end of the process, after the post back. So i have the loader and another image next to it.

is it possible to do a partial post back to hide the image at the start of the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this easily using ASP.NET AJAX JavaScript.

Hide the buttons at [Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(beginRequestHandler)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397432%28v=VS.100%29.aspX)
and show them again at [Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(endRequestHandler)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383810.aspx) events respectively.

As MSDN notes,

**Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager beginRequest Event**

> Raised before the processing of an asynchronous postback starts and the postback request is sent to the server.

**Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager endRequest Event**

> Raised after an asynchronous postback is finished and control has been returned to the browser.